# Manipulate a List in Python that Contains Other Lists

Tags: python, list

I am trying to extract information from a list within a list within a list to end up with something like this from the information below:  ('h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292'), ('h': '0.77521', 'l': '0.77206')

`print(dict)`

`[{'complete': True, 'volume': 2290, 'time': '2021-01-15',  'mid': {'o': '0.77540', 'h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292', 'c': '0.77440'}},  {'complete': True, 'volume': 2312, 'time': '2021-01-15',  'mid': {'o': '0.77436', 'h': '0.77521', 'l': '0.77206', 'c': '0.77206'}}]`

Not sure how to go about it. I tried

`something = list(list(dict.items())[0].items())[3][1]`

`print(something)`

However, this returned {'o': '0.77540', 'h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292', 'c': '0.77440'}

How to get the requested data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following list and dict comprehension

```
dict = [{'complete': True, 'volume': 2290, 'time': '2021-01-15',  'mid': {'o': '0.77540', 'h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292', 'c': '0.77440'}},  {'complete': True, 'volume': 2312, 'time': '2021-01-15',  'mid': {'o': '0.77436', 'h': '0.77521', 'l': '0.77206', 'c': '0.77206'}}]


res = [{k:v for k, v in i['mid'].items() if k in 'hl'} for i in dict]

print(res)
```

Output

```
[{'h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292'}, {'h': '0.77521', 'l': '0.77206'}]
```

Answer (score 1):

First you can take the `mid` child from each parent dictionary in the list.

```
dict = [{'complete': True, 'volume': 2290, 'time': '2021-01-15',  'mid': {'o': '0.77540', 'h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292', 'c': '0.77440'}},  {'complete': True, 'volume': 2312, 'time': '2021-01-15',  'mid': {'o': '0.77436', 'h': '0.77521', 'l': '0.77206', 'c': '0.77206'}}]

old_dict = [dict[0]['mid'],dict[1]['mid']]
```

Then loop through those entries and filter based off the keys (i.e. remove `o` and `c`):

```
list_you_want = []

for i in [0,1]:
    list_you_want.append({ your_key: old_dict[i][your_key] for your_key in ['h','l'] })
```

Which gives you:

```
[{'h': '0.77584', 'l': '0.77292'}, {'h': '0.77521', 'l': '0.77206'}]
```